# Disabling protocols using SQL Server Configuration Manager or ENDPOINTs

Tags: sql-server, network

Besides SQL Server Configuration Manager, it's possible to disable access to specific SQL Server protocols by disabling the default `ENDPOINTs`, but what's the difference between the two options?

Are there security concerns regarding disabling one and not the other? (Should I disable both?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable the endpoint another endpoint of that connection type could be created.  If you disable the protocol in the config manager no endpoints for that connection type will ever work.

There's no security issue as normal authentication is required for all connection types.